# Docker : Unable to access the IBM MQ web management console

Tags: spring-boot, docker, ibm-mq

I followed the article - https://github.com/nuviosoftware/custom-ibm-mq and deployed the container using the below commands in my windows laptop using docker for desktop

```
docker build -t nuviosoftware-mq-local .
docker volume create qm1data
```

and executed

```
docker run --env LICENSE=accept --env MQ_QMGR_NAME=QM1 --volume qm1data:/mnt/mqm --publish 1414:1414 --publish 9443:9443  --env MQ_APP_PASSWORD=passw0rd nuviosoftware-mq-local
```

below is the container log

```
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (windows/amd64) and no specific platform was requested
2021-07-15T08:58:20.659Z CPU architecture: amd64
2021-07-15T08:58:20.659Z Linux kernel version: 4.19.27-linuxkit
2021-07-15T08:58:20.661Z Base image: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.3 (Ootpa)
2021-07-15T08:58:20.661Z Running as user ID 0 with primary group 0
2021-07-15T08:58:20.661Z Capabilities (bounding set): chown,dac_override,fowner,fsetid,kill,setgid,setuid,setpcap,net_bind_service,net_raw,sys_chroot,mknod,audit_write,setfcap
2021-07-15T08:58:20.661Z seccomp enforcing mode: disabled
2021-07-15T08:58:20.661Z Process security attributes: none
2021-07-15T08:58:20.661Z Detected '9p' volume mounted to /mnt/mqm
2021-07-15T08:58:25.540Z Using queue manager name: QM1
2021-07-15T08:58:27.316Z Created directory structure under /var/mqm
2021-07-15T08:58:27.316Z Image created: 2021-03-12T09:57:54+00:00
2021-07-15T08:58:27.316Z Image tag: ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev:9.2.2.0-r1.20210312094918.14987c1-amd64
2021-07-15T08:58:27.794Z MQ version: 9.2.2.0
2021-07-15T08:58:27.794Z MQ level: p922-L210310.DE
2021-07-15T08:58:27.794Z MQ license: Developer
2021-07-15T08:58:29.405Z Creating queue manager QM1
2021-07-15T08:58:29.405Z Starting web server
2021-07-15T08:58:29.652Z Detected existing queue manager QM1
2021-07-15T08:58:29.675Z Error 126 starting web server: AMQ5061E: Program 'strmqweb' cannot be run with root privileges.

2021-07-15T08:58:29.675Z Error starting web server: exit status 126
2021-07-15T08:58:29.982Z Removing existing ServiceComponent configuration
2021-07-15T08:58:29.991Z Starting queue manager
2021-07-15T08:58:31.031Z AMQ5657W: The system resource RLIMIT_NOFILE is set at an unusually low level for IBM MQ. [ArithInsert1(1024), ArithInsert2(10240), CommentInsert1(RLIMIT_NOFILE)]
2021-07-15T08:58:31.216Z AMQ5657W: The system resource RLIMIT_NPROC is set at an unusually low level for IBM MQ. [ArithInsert1(3844), ArithInsert2(4096), CommentInsert1(RLIMIT_NPROC)]
2021-07-15T08:58:31.962Z AMQ5775I: Successfully applied automatic configuration INI definitions. [CommentInsert1(INI)]
2021-07-15T08:58:36.368Z Initializing MQ Advanced for Developers custom authentication service
2021-07-15T08:58:39.939Z AMQ5051I: The queue manager task 'LOGGER-IO' has started. [ArithInsert2(1), CommentInsert1(LOGGER-IO)]
2021-07-15T08:58:42.052Z AMQ7229I: 6 log records accessed on queue manager 'QM1' during the log replay phase. [ArithInsert1(6), CommentInsert1(QM1)]
2021-07-15T08:58:42.104Z AMQ7230I: Log replay for queue manager 'QM1' complete. [ArithInsert1(6), CommentInsert1(QM1)]
2021-07-15T08:58:42.244Z AMQ5051I: The queue manager task 'CHECKPOINT' has started. [ArithInsert2(1), CommentInsert1(CHECKPOINT)]
2021-07-15T08:58:42.359Z AMQ7231I: 0 log records accessed on queue manager 'QM1' during the recovery phase. [CommentInsert1(QM1)]
2021-07-15T08:58:42.405Z AMQ7232I: Transaction manager state recovered for queue manager 'QM1'. [CommentInsert1(QM1)]
2021-07-15T08:58:42.542Z AMQ7233I: 0 out of 0 in-flight transactions resolved for queue manager 'QM1'. [CommentInsert1(QM1)]
2021-07-15T08:58:43.559Z AMQ5037I: The queue manager task 'APP-SIGNAL' has started. [ArithInsert2(1), CommentInsert1(APP-SIGNAL)]
2021-07-15T08:58:43.603Z AMQ5037I: The queue manager task 'APP-SIGNAL' has started. [ArithInsert2(2), CommentInsert1(APP-SIGNAL)]
2021-07-15T08:58:43.643Z AMQ5037I: The queue manager task 'APP-SIGNAL' has started. [ArithInsert2(3), CommentInsert1(APP-SIGNAL)]
2021-07-15T08:58:43.689Z AMQ5037I: The queue manager task 'APP-SIGNAL' has started. [ArithInsert2(4), CommentInsert1(APP-SIGNAL)]
2021-07-15T08:58:43.731Z AMQ5037I: The queue manager task 'APP-SIGNAL' has started. [ArithInsert2(5), CommentInsert1(APP-SIGNAL)]
2021-07-15T08:58:43.793Z AMQ5037I: The queue manager task 'ERROR-LOG' has started. [ArithInsert2(1), CommentInsert1(ERROR-LOG)]
2021-07-15T08:58:43.822Z AMQ5037I: The queue manager task 'APP-SIGNAL' has started. [ArithInsert2(6), CommentInsert1(APP-SIGNAL)]
2021-07-15T08:58:43.849Z AMQ5037I: The queue manager task 'APP-SIGNAL' has started. [ArithInsert2(7), CommentInsert1(APP-SIGNAL)]
2021-07-15T08:58:43.896Z AMQ5037I: The queue manager task 'APP-SIGNAL' has started. [ArithInsert2(8), CommentInsert1(APP-SIGNAL)]
2021-07-15T08:58:45.037Z AMQ8003I: IBM MQ queue manager 'QM1' started using V9.2.2.0. [CommentInsert1(9.2.2.0), CommentInsert3(QM1)]
2021-07-15T08:58:45.551Z AMQ5051I: The queue manager task 'DUR-SUBS-MGR' has started. [ArithInsert2(1), CommentInsert1(DUR-SUBS-MGR)]
2021-07-15T08:58:45.559Z AMQ9410I: Repository manager started.
2021-07-15T08:58:45.643Z AMQ5051I: The queue manager task 'TOPIC-TREE' has started. [ArithInsert2(1), CommentInsert1(TOPIC-TREE)]
2021-07-15T08:58:45.689Z AMQ5024I: The command server has started. ProcessId(135). [ArithInsert1(135), CommentInsert1(SYSTEM.CMDSERVER.1)]
2021-07-15T08:58:45.758Z AMQ5022I: The channel initiator has started. ProcessId(137). [ArithInsert1(137), CommentInsert1(SYSTEM.CHANNEL.INITQ)]
2021-07-15T08:58:45.802Z AMQ5051I: The queue manager task 'AUTOCONFIG' has started. [ArithInsert2(1), CommentInsert1(AUTOCONFIG)]
2021-07-15T08:58:45.838Z AMQ5051I: The queue manager task 'IQM-COMMS-MANAGER' has started. [ArithInsert2(1), CommentInsert1(IQM-COMMS-MANAGER)]
2021-07-15T08:58:46.262Z AMQ8942I: Starting to process automatic MQSC configuration script.
2021-07-15T08:58:46.291Z AMQ8024I: IBM MQ channel initiator started. [CommentInsert1(SYSTEM.CHANNEL.INITQ)]
2021-07-15T08:58:59.758Z AMQ8939I: Automatic MQSC configuration script has completed, and contained 24 command(s), of which 0 had errors. [ArithInsert1(24), CommentInsert1(0)]
2021-07-15T08:58:59.809Z AMQ5051I: The queue manager task 'ACTVTRC' has started. [ArithInsert2(1), CommentInsert1(ACTVTRC)]
2021-07-15T08:58:59.818Z AMQ5037I: The queue manager task 'DEFERRED_DELIVERY' has started. [ArithInsert2(1), CommentInsert1(DEFERRED_DELIVERY)]
2021-07-15T08:58:59.831Z AMQ5052I: The queue manager task 'QPUBSUB-CTRLR' has started. [ArithInsert2(1), CommentInsert1(QPUBSUB-CTRLR)]
2021-07-15T08:58:59.840Z AMQ5051I: The queue manager task 'EXPIRER' has started. [ArithInsert2(1), CommentInsert1(EXPIRER)]
2021-07-15T08:58:59.846Z AMQ5037I: The queue manager task 'DEFERRED-MSG' has started. [ArithInsert2(1), CommentInsert1(DEFERRED-MSG)]
2021-07-15T08:58:59.859Z AMQ5052I: The queue manager task 'QPUBSUB-SUBPT-NLCACHE' has started. [ArithInsert2(1), CommentInsert1(QPUBSUB-SUBPT-NLCACHE)]
2021-07-15T08:58:59.867Z AMQ5051I: The queue manager task 'Q-DELETION' has started. [ArithInsert2(1), CommentInsert1(Q-DELETION)]
2021-07-15T08:58:59.879Z AMQ5052I: The queue manager task 'QPUBSUB-QUEUE-NLCACHE' has started. [ArithInsert2(1), CommentInsert1(QPUBSUB-QUEUE-NLCACHE)]
2021-07-15T08:58:59.882Z AMQ5037I: The queue manager task 'STATISTICS' has started. [ArithInsert2(1), CommentInsert1(STATISTICS)]
2021-07-15T08:58:59.892Z AMQ5051I: The queue manager task 'ASYNCQ' has started. [ArithInsert2(1), CommentInsert1(ASYNCQ)]
2021-07-15T08:58:59.915Z AMQ5051I: The queue manager task 'RESOURCE_MONITOR' has started. [ArithInsert2(1), CommentInsert1(RESOURCE_MONITOR)]
2021-07-15T08:58:59.918Z AMQ5037I: The queue manager task 'MARKINTSCAN' has started. [ArithInsert2(1), CommentInsert1(MARKINTSCAN)]
2021-07-15T08:58:59.930Z AMQ5052I: The queue manager task 'PUBSUB-DAEMON' has started. [ArithInsert2(1), CommentInsert1(PUBSUB-DAEMON)]
2021-07-15T08:58:59.930Z AMQ5975I: 'IBM MQ Distributed Pub/Sub Controller' has started. [CommentInsert1(IBM MQ Distributed Pub/Sub Controller)]
2021-07-15T08:58:59.966Z AMQ5026I: The listener 'SYSTEM.LISTENER.TCP.1' has started. ProcessId(174). [ArithInsert1(174), CommentInsert1(SYSTEM.LISTENER.TCP.1)]
2021-07-15T08:58:59.984Z AMQ5051I: The queue manager task 'PRESERVED-Q' has started. [ArithInsert2(1), CommentInsert1(PRESERVED-Q)]
2021-07-15T08:59:00.011Z AMQ5051I: The queue manager task 'MULTICAST' has started. [ArithInsert2(1), CommentInsert1(MULTICAST)]
2021-07-15T08:59:00.142Z Started queue manager
2021-07-15T08:59:00.142Z Metrics are disabled
2021-07-15T08:59:00.225Z AMQ5975I: 'IBM MQ Distributed Pub/Sub Command Task' has started. [CommentInsert1(IBM MQ Distributed Pub/Sub Command Task)]
2021-07-15T08:59:00.279Z AMQ5975I: 'IBM MQ Distributed Pub/Sub Publish Task' has started. [CommentInsert1(IBM MQ Distributed Pub/Sub Publish Task)]
2021-07-15T08:59:00.294Z AMQ5975I: 'IBM MQ Distributed Pub/Sub Fan Out Task' has started. [CommentInsert1(IBM MQ Distributed Pub/Sub Fan Out Task)]
2021-07-15T08:59:00.498Z AMQ5806I: Queued Publish/Subscribe Daemon started for queue manager QM1. [CommentInsert1(QM1)]
2021-07-15T08:59:07.843Z AMQ5041I: The queue manager task 'AUTOCONFIG' has ended. [CommentInsert1(AUTOCONFIG)]
```

however I could access the web management console

[image]

as well as I could not connect with the MQ from the client application

```
2021-07-15 14:31:40.922 ERROR 4884 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'ORDER.RESPONSE' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=0, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager 'QM1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1414)'.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
2021-07-15 14:31:47.368 ERROR 4884 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'ORDER.RESPONSE' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=1, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager 'QM1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1414)'.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED')
```

Comment: it appears that the MQ service is not able to properly start in your container according to the 2 error lines in your output

2021-07-15T08:58:29.675Z Error 126 starting web server: AMQ5061E: Program 'strmqweb' cannot be run with root privileges.

2021-07-15T08:58:29.675Z Error starting web server: exit status 126

which would explain why you cannot reach it

Comment: You are getting MQRC 2035 - which is "Not Authorised" reason code. The user under which client application is running does not have the authority to access your destination ORDER.RESPONSE. You will need to use setqmaut command set authority on the destinaton.

Comment: I think @meaningqo is correct. However, we had one guy that was using windows that had similar strange problems that could only be resolved by complete reset of docker desktop there. In general the web-interface works fine without fine tuned authorisation settings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was using the windows mode and switched to Linux mod, it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try to access it through with https:
https://localhost:9443/ibmmq/console

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns, you can use this to access its management console

> You can use the MQ Web Console to create the model queue. Access the MQ Web Console for your MQ running as a container at https://localhost:9443/ibmmq/console/. You can log in with the default admin details or your own, if you made changes.